# Getting Julia SharedArrays to play nicely with Sun Grid Engine

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, julia, sungridengine

I have been trying to get a Julia program to run correctly in an SGE environment with `SharedArray`s. I read several threads on Julia and SGE, but most of them seem to deal with MPI. The function `bind_pe_procs()` from [this](https://gist.github.com/tlamadon/636d8e468b328d23bb4d) Gist seems to correctly bind the processes to a local environment. A script like

```
### define bind_pe_procs() as in Gist
### ...
println("Started julia")
bind_pe_procs()
println("do SharedArrays initialize correctly?")
x = SharedArray(Float64, 3, pids = procs(), init = S -> S[localindexes(S)] = 1.0)
pids = procs(x)
println("number of workers: ", length(procs()))
println("SharedArrays map to ", length(pids), " workers")
```

yields the following output:

```
starting qsub script file
Mon Oct 12 15:13:38 PDT 2015
calling mpirun now 
exception on 2: exception on exception on 4: exception on exception on 53: : exception on exception on exception on Started julia
parsing PE_HOSTFILE
[{"name"=>"compute-0-8.local","n"=>"5"}]compute-0-8.local
ASCIIString["compute-0-8.local","compute-0-8.local","compute-0-8.local","compute-0-8.local"]adding machines to current system
done
do SharedArrays initialize correctly?
number of workers: 5
SharedArrays map to 5 workers
```

Curiously, this doesn't seem to work if I need to load the array from a file and convert to `SharedArray` format with the command `convert(SharedArray, vec(readdlm(FILEPATH)))`. If the script is

```
println("Started julia")
bind_pe_procs()

### script reads arrays from file and converts to SharedArrays
println("running script...")
my_script()
```

then the result is garbage:

```
starting qsub script file
Mon Oct 19 09:18:29 PDT 2015
calling mpirun now Started julia
parsing PE_HOSTFILE
[{"name"=>"compute-0-5.local","n"=>"11"}]compute-0-5.local
ASCIIString["compute-0-5.local","compute-0-5.local","compute-0-5.local","compute-0-5.local","compute-0-5.local","compute-0-5.local","compute-0-5.local","compute-0-5.local","compute-0-5.local","compute-0- 5.local"]adding machines to current system
done
running script...
Current number of processes: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
SharedArray y is seen by [1] processes
### tons of errors here
### important one is "SharedArray cannot be used on a non-participating process"
```

so somehow the SharedArrays do not map correctly to all cores. Does anybody have any suggestions or insights into this problem?

Comment: Do mind that `procs()` is different from `workers()`. The first may include non-worker processes. Specially since `addprocs()`, used in sge.jl, adds _remote_ machines.

Comment: Pardon the late response @FelipeLema! You point out an important detail. But so far, I am still stuck :(. Interested readers can also see the following [issue](https://github.com/JuliaParallel/ClusterManagers.jl/issues/34) that I filed at the [ClusterManagers.jl](https://github.com/JuliaParallel/ClusterManagers.jl) repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround that I have used in my work is to simply force SGE to submit a job to a particular node and then limit the parallel environment to the number of cores that I want to use.

Below I provide an SGE qsub script for a 24-core node where I want to use only 6 cores.

```
#!/bin/bash
# lots of available SGE script options, only relevant ones included below

# request processes in parallel environment 
#$ -pe orte 6 

# use this command to dump job on a particular queue/node
#$ -q all.q@compute-0-13

/share/apps/julia-0.4.0/bin/julia -p 5 MY_SCRIPT.jl
```

Pro: plays nicely with `SharedArray`s.
Con: the job will wait in the queue until the node has sufficient cores available.